# What is wrong with the below code when I am trying to count the password fields?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

What is wrong with the below code? According to linda, `getElementsByTagName`is supposed to return an `array`, so basically it is supposed to work just fine.Please help explaining to me what is going wrong?

```
var outputs= 0;
function countPasswds(){
    var v= document;
    d=v.getElementsByTagName("input");
    x= d.getAttribute("type");
    for (var i=0; i< d.length; i++){
        if (x[i] == "password")
            outputs++;
    }
    console.log("Number of Password Fields is: ", outputs);
}
```

Comment: Unless you need support for older browsers, you could also use `querySelectorAll`: `var count = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]').length;`   ( https://jsfiddle.net/f4oyhqcs/ )

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    x= d.getAttribute("type");
> ```

You are trying to get the type attribute from the document.

You have to check the type attribute of **each input**, you can't just get it once and reuse it everywhere.

Move your get attribute call inside the for loop and apply it to the element object.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it for you, pls try this:

```
function countPasswds() {
    var inputType;
    var outputs = 0;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputType = inputs[i].getAttribute("type");
        if (inputType == "password")
            outputs++;
    }
    console.log("Number of Password Fields is: ", outputs);
}
```

There were many problems with your function.
First of all don't use one character variable names, it makes your code extremly hard to read or understand.

You've setup the `for` loop for the number of `input` elements, but inside of the loop, tried to get `'i'-th` the value of `x`.

The main part of the fix was to move the `getAttribute` function inside of the loop.

Comment: I've added some explanation, hope it helps.